# Deconstructing the expression

Tags: c++, syntax, sfinae

With reference to [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), how does the expression within the brackets deconstruct?

```
template <int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 0] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is even
}
template <int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 1] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is odd
}
```

I am trying to read this overload resolution, assuming I is even, and obeying operator precedence rules:

```
deconstruct 1: template<int I> div(char (*) [1] = 0) //since I % 2 == 0
```

So is it correct to read the above as follows:

the template function `div` expects a function pointer argument, whose signature is `char (*) [int I = 1]`, defaulting to 0 or NULL?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: An array bound of `[1]` is valid, a bound of `[0]` is not. So the value of `I` that makes `[I % 2 == 0]` the same as `[0]` takes the overload out of consideration. That's SFINAE.

Comment: The parameter of `div` is not a function pointer, it's a pointer to an array of `char`, of length `1` or `0`. Except that `0` is not a valid length for an array.

Comment: These are function declarations, not expressions. If by "brackets" you mean parentheses, that is a function parameter with no name and a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we call it like `div<21>`, the compiler tries to substitute `I = 21` into the templates.  We get:  (`__div21` is the name of the hypothetical function resulted from substitution)

```
void __div21(char(*)[0] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is even
}
void __div21(char(*)[1] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is odd
}
```

An array of zero length is ill-formed, so the first version is a substitution failure.  It is removed from overload resolution.  The second version is fine, so it participates in overload resolution.  Therefore, `div<21>` calls the second overload.

---

If we call it like `div<42>`, the compiler tries to substitute `I = 42` into the templates.  We get:  (`__div42` is the name of the hypothetical function resulted from substitution)

```
void __div42(char(*)[1] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is even
}
void __div42(char(*)[0] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is odd
}
```

An array of zero length is ill-formed, so the second version is a substitution failure.  It is removed from overload resolution.  The first version is fine, so it participates in overload resolution.  Therefore, `div<42>` calls the first overload.

---

Since C++17, we can make the code more easily comprehensible by using the `if constexpr` construct:

```
template <int I>
void div()
{
    if constexpr (I % 2 == 0)
        /* handle even case */;
    else
        /* handle odd case */;
}
```